# Armor for a pyrokinetic

Tags: medieval, super-powers, armors, fire

What could a group of pyrokinetics wear.

- They can't wear armor made from flammable material (obviously).
- They can't wear iron/steel armor because it would get hot too quickly and it wouldn't be so practical for them.
- They mostly use one-handed swords.
- Also they have to absorb fire or heat before they start making fire and they have a absorption limit. So if they absorb too much heat they would burn themselves.
- Era is similar to medieval era but there can be exceptions in some senses.

Comment: What are they worried about getting hit with? Bullets, swords, or other magic? Possibly all three?

Comment: Swords rocks warhammers in some cases arrows.but Not magic.

Answer (score 6):

**Leather**

<s>Fireproof</s> Fire retardant if treated right, tough, hardwearing, and with a proven track record of being used as armour already. You can make stiff leather plates if you so wish and you’ve got a capable tanner.

Also easy to make compared to mail or plate, and you can even etch cool designs into it.

Plus: you’ll look bitchin’ wearing black leather and flames.

Comment: I think it really suits when main character plays electro guitar in a rock band (who is also pyrokinetic)

Comment: leather armor is a bit expensive because you need the right leather or it serves no purpose, (ox back leather was prefered) cost wise it  was not as bad as plate but comparable to chain. You would think leather would be cheap but it needed leather from quite expensive animals. You can also sandwich metal between leather (that is what most "leather" armor was) no exposed metal to absorb/conduct heat,the type of leather does not matter as much for that type.

Comment: They aren't that big of a group of so they can afford leather armor without any problems. As for the sandwich armor i think  it could work pretty well

Answer (score 2):

as @joe Bloggs already mention leather, i suggest boiled leather armor with extra diping or soaked the boiled leather armor with urine and vinegar just extra case because this help extinguished greek fire (and hopefully the urine can cool down the heat) according to wiki link here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_fire

> In attempting to reconstruct the Greek fire system, the concrete evidence, as it emerges from the contemporary literary references, provides the following characteristics:
>
> It burned on water, and, according to some interpretations, was
> ignited by water. In addition, as numerous writers testify, it could
> be extinguished only by a few substances, such as sand (which deprived
> it of oxygen), strong vinegar, or old urine, presumably by some sort
> of chemical reaction

and the best part is you can make [boiled leather armor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boiled_leather) (not the rock star leather jacket that you think of but real practical hard leather armor) using [boiled urine](https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmXoypizjW3WknFiJnKLwHCnL72vedxjQkDDP1mXWo6uco/wiki/Boiled_leather.html), urine is part of traditional [leather process](https://dumpstatadventures.com/the-gm-is-always-right/making-tools-useful-in-5e-leatherworkers-tools) anyway.

Comment: I know how leather armor looks and I know they're not leather jacket but I think they still look like something a metal band could wear

Comment: @AIwithstick ah...ok although real boiled leather armor look more like plate armor though, so in my opinion i dont think it really suit with usual metal band wear like most fantasy leather armor depict at, but its your fiction after all and iam just saying....

Answer (score 1):

**Nothing.**

Everything that is nice to wear is flammable.  Metal gets too hot.  Asbestos cloth is workable but it is scratchy, especially, well...  It is scratchy, OK?

Your pyros go about in the buff.  Or perhaps wear warm robes that they can quickly ditch when it is pyro time, then find later once the flames are done.

Also, when you see a bunch of naked people striding towards you thru the dusk, clothed in nothing but a sword in one hand, it is scary.